# How to create SQL query results in columns from rows?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

From the following tables:

- store(store_id, ...) {1 ..., 2 ...} two stores
- film(film_id, ...)
- inventory(inventory_id, film_id, store_id)
- rental(rental_id, rental_date, inventory_id, return_date, ...)
- category(category_id, name)
- film_category(film_id, category_id)
- film(film_id, rental_duration, rental_rate, ...)
- customer(customer_id, store_id, ...)

Can I have a query results on a table just like the following?

```
CategoryName | "Store 1: avaliable items" | "Store 1: unavaliable items" | "Store 2: avaliable items" | "Store 2: unavaliable items"
```

Notice that the store fileds in the result table are in separate columns not in the same columns.

I am not looking for the result query, I am looking for how to make them side by side store 1, store 2.

Can a case SQL statement help here?

Answer (score 0):

get your data in the following form (may be you have to union multiple selects)

```
category item             count
-------- ---------        -----
cat 1    store1-avail     a1
cat 1    store1-unavail   b1
cat 1    store2-avail     c1
cat 1    store2-unavail   d1
cat 2    store1-avail     a2
cat 2    store1-unavail   b2
```

and then use the [pivot function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to tranform it to your desired layout

```
category  store1-avail store1-unavail store2-avail ...
--------- ------------ -------------- ------------
cat 1     a1           b1             c1
cat 2     a2           b2             c2
...
```